# css text color not working but background color is

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where the text color is not changing on a menu item, but the background color is?

The html is as follows…

```
<nav><ul>
<li class="active"> <a href="index.cfm" class="NavHome" title="Home" >Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="aboutus.cfm" class="NavAboutUs" title="About" >About us</a></li>
<li> <a href="services.cfm" class="NavServices" title="Services" >Services</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

And the CSS is as follows…

```
nav { margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; padding:75px 0px 0px 0px;  }
nav ul { overflow:hidden; list-style: none; }
nav li { float:left; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; text-transform:uppercase;  text-align:left; }
nav li a { text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF; display:block; height:32px; padding:5px 0px 0px 10px; }
nav .active a {color:#40404d; background-image:url(../images/button-on-left.gif), url(../images/button-on-right.gif); background-position:top left, top right; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:#ffffff; }
nav li a:hover {color:#40404d; background-image:url(../images/button-on-left.gif), url(../images/button-on-right.gif); background-position:top left, top right; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:#ffffff; }
nav .last {background:none;}

.NavHome { width:55px;}
.NavAboutUs { width:80px;}
.NavServices { width:145px;}
```

I have tried using the `!important` method on the color style but with no luck.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is applying correct only. what is the problem? what color you are expecting?

Comment: The background color is white. So, how do you want to see white on white?

Comment: You want the text color on menu to change basically? or you want it to change on hover? I don't understand... its already applying correctly. correct me if am wrong?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I am trying to change the text color to #40404d when you hover over the menu item, so in the hover state, (nav li a:hover) I have set the color:#40404d; but its not working (all other styles are working, for example background-color:#ffffff; is working on rollover.

Comment: It is working fine. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/qdx6ppc7/. When you hover the link it is showing. Initially it was white.

Comment: ok, many thanks Suresh, it must something else in the styles sheet that is affecting the site. But yes, in the fiddle its working.

Answer (score 0):

Your font and background is set to color: #fff (white).

If I understood correctly, **you can try:**

```
nav li a { text-decoration:none; color:#000; display:block; height:32px; padding:5px 0px 0px 10px; }
```

Add this after nav li a.

**Code:**
You can set it the colour you require.

```
a:hover{
   color: green; 
}
```

This will work and change the font colour on hover.

[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gh8gbp70/1/)

Comment: Hi, sadly no joy, the text on hover dose not change? I have tried this but no joy…

Comment: `nav li { color:#FFFFFF; float:left; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; text-transform:uppercase;  text-align:left; }
nav li a:link { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; display:block; height:32px; padding:5px 0px 0px 10px; }
nav li a:visited { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; display:block; height:32px; padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;  }
nav li a:hover {color:#40404d; background-image:url(../images/button-on-left.gif), url(../images/button-on-right.gif); background-position:top left, top right; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:#ffffff; }`

Comment: oh so you want text on hover to change. Please see me updated answer @elixireu